# Nextcloud calendar synchronisation stops in Kontact

Tags: kubuntu, calendar, nextcloud, kontact, caldav

For some time now I am facing troubles with kontact and nextcloud synchronisation. Caldav synchronisation.

Connecting kontact to my nextcloud instance works nicley and all the calendar dates are downloaded. After some time synchronisation seems to stop without an obvious reason.

Problem is: I do think (but am not sure) when i try to move a calendar date from one day to another, something is stopping the sync process and nothing is syncing anymore. Closing and reopening or manually triggering the sync process does nothing at all anymore.

I have tried to install kontact from different sources but the problem persists.

Deleting and readding the caldav calendar does resync all dates but after sometime the same problem reappears.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

1. Move a date / Create a date /  change a date
2. nothing is synced anymore

SOFTWARE/OS VERSIONS
Linux/KDE Plasma: kubuntu 20.04
(available in About System)
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8

UPDATE. I think I found the a solution:
Okay I tried to debug the problems...I found a working solution (seems to work will see for the future)

...Reinstalled the flatpak at flathub:
`sudo flatpak install flathub org.kde.kontact`

Then there seems to be a bug which is described here:
https://syve.wordpress.com/2020/05/24/akonadi-bug-qlocalsocketconnecttoserver-invalid-name/

I just did remove the databases with:

`akonadictl stop`

`mv $HOME/.local/share/akonadi/db_data $HOME/.local/share/akonadi/db_data_old`

Attention because this removes all the data and calendars! So better backup before if you are unsure.

and then readded the calendars and everything seems to work...hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i had success while running through this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210603/qt-and-openssl-incompatible-version-on-ubuntu#52210604

That is definitely the problem here.

In my case the solution was easy. Just install libssl-dev:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

did the trick. There are some symlinks missing or incompatibilities in qt networking and openssl...